# How to translate violation messages in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I have built a form using a form builder in Symfony and in my form below

```
 $builder->add(
            'Firstname',
            TextType::class,
            [
                'translation_domain' => 'transbundle',
                'label' => 'Tam_bum.Firstname',
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ]
        );
```

my en.yml file I have specified

```
  Tam_bum:
      Firstname: First Name
      Errormessage: Does not exist
```

which works for my form when ever languages are switched on the translation option.

Now I'm trying to also apply this concept to a violation I am calling

```
->buildViolation('Tam_bum.Errormessage')
```

But what I get is an outputted value of this `"Tam_bum.Errormessage"`

My expectation was that I would get the translated value for "Tam_bum.Errormessage", please help to guide in doing this in the correct way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint message in form validation use the validators domain.

If you are using symfony 5, you should add the tanslation in your file `validators.en.php` (or yaml, or xml depending on your translation format) in the translations folders

Comment: I really do not understand how to do this technically, any example in usage

Comment: btw, I have a translation file which I specified up in my question its en.yml

Comment: You can find example usage in the symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html

Comment: plus i suggest you read this documentation about translation domain to understand how it works: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations